# Storing different Array Types in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, web-services, list

I request different SOAP webservices in a C# Programm and handle each result (`Webservice1[]` and `Webservice2[]`) in different classes but I want to wrap each type of array into the same array or `List<T>` of items.

How can i do that, any suggestions?

Regards
Rene

Comment: Do they have a same base class/interface?

Comment: No they have different base class. I just want a list or a array of items to handle the Array in the same function. I can create a wrapper class to create a list of prop/value over reflection? is there a simple way or do i create a own class?

Comment: Is there a Type like List<prop,value>

Comment: @kockiren:  Do you mean something like System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<key, value>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a bit on context ;p If they have the *exact same* API, i.e. they are the same service at two endpoints, then maybe use *one* service (and change the URL manually), or use WCF which can re-use types between services.

However, a more generic approach would be to exploit `partial class` to make both implement a common interface, i.e. if they both have a `.Foo` property that you care about, you should be able to do:

```
namespace SomeNamespace {
    public interface ICommon {
        int Foo {get;}
    }
}
namespace Webservice1Namespace {
    partial class Webservice1 : ICommon {  }
}
namespace Webservice2Namespace {
    partial class Webservice2 : ICommon {  }
}
// note we didn't add a .Foo implementation - that comes from the
// *other* half of the partial classes, as per the .designer.cs
```

This uses implicit interface implementation to map the `Foo` from `Webservice1` and `Webservice2` to `ICommon`. Now you can have an `ICommon[]` and add instances of either `Webservice1` or `Webservice2`, and access the `.Foo` property of each.

Another approach, of course, is to use `dynamic[]`, which would *also* allow you to access `.Foo`, but which throws type-safety out of the window in the process (along with anything that uses reflection, such as data-binding etc).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's possible or not, but could you try returning something like object[]?  This would obviate the need to create a custom base class.  Otherwise, perhaps creating a base class for Webservice1 and Webservice2 would allow you to return something like Baseclass[].  Have you looked at WCF, DataContracts, and inheritance?  It might allow you a better framework for dealing with these sorts of things, imho.